# Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable: x64 или x86

Tags: windows, c++, visual-c++

Есть 2 версии - x86 и x64. У меня есть программа x86, использующая этот пакет, а ОС у меня x64. Какую версию из этих двух пакетов мне надо установить, для того чтобы моя программа работала? В общих случаях надо установить пакет с той же архитектуры, что и программа, или надо установить пакет с той же архитектуры, что и ОС?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Той-же, что и программа. [Поддержка 32-битных приложений в 64-битной среде Windows](http://software.intel.com/ru-ru/articles/02_Support_of_32-bit_applications/)